# Python + Selenium + ChromeDriver: ElementNotInteractableException when trying to click on a class name

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

```py
driver.find_element_by_class_name("logo-cainiao_standard").click()
```

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/33012171050.html

I'm not able to click on the Standard Shipping when you select the shipping logistics under the price you click and a table open so you can chose the shipping logistics you want

With the dev tools it show a class name as per above

Thanks!

[See Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydHH8.jpg)

Comment: It _might_ be because of an incorrect selector. Try opening the URL in devtools and running document.querySelector. After evaluating it in the console, mouse over the matched element and check if the option box lights up.

Comment: Can you mark and attach image here because i could not identify your element?

Comment: Steps to reach the _Standard Shipping_ element?

Comment: You have to click under the price on the shipping to open the shipping table with the choice